# Xamarin generates double APK

Tags: android, xamarin, apk, jarsigner

When I try to sign my APK for release, Xamarin often generates two apk, one that simply has package name, and another named "packagename"+"-signed".

Both are signed with my certificate if I try to verify it in command prompt with jarsigner.

What is the problem, if it is? Did it happened to someone else?

Comment: How do you generate your APK?

Comment: Sorry, I deleted it. I generate it with the normal procedure with Xamarin.

Comment: Like this https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/signing/

Comment: Probably the -signed is not zip-aligned

Comment: You should use the `Archive Workflow` to generate your APKs. You are most likely manually generating apks - [https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_2_-_signing_the_android_application_package/manually-signing-the-apk/](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_2_-_signing_the_android_application_package/manually-signing-the-apk/)

Comment: @marcosVasconcelos how do I run the command to check it?

Comment: no idea, check the build logs to see it

Comment: both apps success to install and to run, but I get a strange behavior with the "-signed" one. In the field where I print the version, i get 1 instead of 1.5, that the other one is showing right. I don't know what to think

Comment: copying C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\Archives\2018-01-05\....apkarchive\signed-apks\[packagename].apk to C:\...\[packagename]-Signed.apk
SUCCESS:Il pacchetto '[packagename].apk' è stato creato in C:\...\[packagename]-Signed.apk

copying C:\...\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\Archives\2018-01-05\....apkarchive\signed-apks\[packagename].apk to C:\...\[packagename].apk
SUCCESS:Il pacchetto '[packagename].apk' è stato creato in C:\....\[packagename].apk

In a log I read this

Comment: both versions if checked are zipaligned appearently